# I want to return response in XML form from REST API in java

Tags: java, xml, api, rest

I have REST API in java that take image file and save on the server i want to return the path of that uploaded image in XML form but don't know how to do it.Currently it returns the response as a string in the browser.

Here is my code.

```
package com.javacodegeeks.enterprise.rest.jersey;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/files")
public class JerseyFileUpload {

    private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "/home/hassan/Downloads/";

    /**
     * Upload a File
     */

    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
            @FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
            @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {

        String filePath = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();

        // save the file to the server
        saveFile(fileInputStream, filePath);

        String output = "File saved to server location : " + filePath;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to a defined location on the server
    private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
            String serverLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            outpuStream.flush();
            outpuStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve your purported problem, but I would expect that the location of the image file would be returned in the `Location` header of the response.

Comment: `output` is a string. You need to return an entity (instance) of a class that is annotated with `@XmlElement`

Comment: Can i use Produces annotation as well in this same class because Consumes annotation is also here can i use both at same time.@RobAu how to use  @XmlElement as i am pretty new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return xml from Rest, try to create Object with some fields. and Object and field will have @XmlRootElement @XmlElement and put @Produces("application/xml") on top of method signature.

```
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces("application/xml")
    public Response uploadFile(...){
         //body
   }
```

also you can use `@produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)` instead of `@Produces("application/xml")`. both are same.

Comment: will i have to create object of that class or another class.

Comment: follow below link https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/java-ee/producing-and-consuming-json-or-xml-in-java-rest-services-with-jersey-and-jackson

Comment: Thanks @Tipu It really helps me and solves my problem.